# Laravel, get relationships of single record ($first on a with())

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to add some related model data to my $user object. let me explain :

```
$user = User::find(1); // my user object 
// I want to add my defined user profile from the user_profile relationship
$userdata = $user->with('user_profile')->first();
```

This doesn't work :( It returns the user profile of the first user in my db!

```
$user = User::find(1); // my user object 
// I want to add my defined user profile from the user_profile relationship
$userdata = $user->with('user_profile')->get();
```

This isn't what I need either - user is always a single record in this scenario, not a collection.

So how do I get the related "with" data of $user, and store it in $userdata?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need the user too or only the related data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to get data of All users with associated `user_profile` with eager loading.

```
User::with('user_profile')->get();
```

if you want to get the data of single user you can try.

```
User::with('user_profile')->where('id',$user_id)->first();
```

using `with('relations')` will return all the users and associated data with them.

You can now access them from the object itself:

```
$user = User::with('user_profile')->where('id',$user_id)->first();
$userProfile = $user->user_profile;
```

if the `$user` is already fetched and you want to fetch the associated relationship.

Then you can

```
$user->load('user_profile');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi. I already have the object $user. In fact, I am parsing it. I want to add the user_profile relationship.

Comment: Yes, that's it! $user->load('user_profile'); Thats great :) Eager loading... much quicker.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
$user = User::with('user_profile')->where('id',$user_id)->first();
$user_profile_data = $user->user_profile;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query

Here $user_id is id of the user whose data you want to fetch.

```
User::where('id', $user_id)->with('user_profile')->first()
```

Here you must define user_profile relation in user model

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get related `user_profile`:

```
$userdata = $user->user_profile;
```